# Cann't Find <Directory /var/www> in “000-default” File

Tags: apache, laravel, ubuntu-16.04, web-deployment

I'm working to deploy Laravel 5.3 project to Ubuntu 16.04 Server.
The tutorial I'm following says that there should be

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory /var/www>
```

in the  "/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default" file and I should edit them to be :

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/project/public
<Directory /var/www/project/public>
```

I found :

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
```

**but didn't fin**d :

```
<Directory /var/www>
```

I tried to put it and put this inside the directory tag

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /var/www/project/public
```

but it results in errors while restarting apache.

What should I do ??

Comment: you didn't got `/var/www/html` or `/var/www/public` or `/var/www/` ? don't overwrite the default just copy to your site name and add your own vhost and then add your new site configuration `sudo a2ensite  site.com.conf`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to **copy you default-000.conf** don't overwrited, and ***no from sites-enabled but from sites-available***

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite //active mode rewriting
sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/mysitename.com.conf
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/mysitename.com.conf
```

Paste the vhost :

```
 <Directory /var/www/project/public/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
 </Directory>
```

After this save and do a :

```
sudo a2ensite mysitename.com.conf
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
```

Add an htaccess to you root folder :

```
sudo nano /var/www/project/public/.htaccess
sudo chmod 644 /var/www/project/public/.htaccess
sudo chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www    //to be sure you have rights
sudo service apache2 reload //to take the new configuration
sudo service apache2 restart //apply ...
```

Paste you directive rewriting

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /var/www/project/public
```

Comment: should I add the directory at the end of the file and also change DocumentRoot /var/www  that already exists  at the top of the file to DocumentRoot /var/www/project/public ??

Comment: @Rowayda Khayri yes you can add a directory but don't forget to add right and group property same as you group of www

Comment: @Rowayda Khayri Just adding 2 importants commands. check if you apache group is www-data doing a `ls -la /var/` and look at www wich group is it and add the same on the command above.

Comment: .htaccess already contains "RewriteEngine On" . should I just add "RewriteBase /var/www/project/public" or need to add directive that contain
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /var/www/project/public
at the end of the file after </IfModule> ??

Comment: @RowaydaKhayri no just ignore and use it if is the default .htaccess of your site using.

Comment: I get 403 error :  You don't have permission to access / on this server.. I'm trying to fix it but I don't know what is he problem

Comment: check what wrong with simple : `cat /var/log/apache2/error.log or a tail -n 15 /var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: I had to run "sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf" after "sudo a2ensite mysitename.com.conf" and then : 
"sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php " 
 "a2enmod php7.0"
"sudo a2dismod mpm_event"
"sudo a2enmod mpm_prefork"
"sudo service apache2 restart " 
and it works now . Thanks @headmax

Comment: Good happy for you, thanks for closed the topic, and if wanted to accept the anwser ty too ;). Good luck for the next. @Rowayda Khayri